# Accessing an array using pointer is not working during porting to ARM

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-optimization

I am new to the ARM platform.

Below code has been used in an function for finding out the conjugate multiplication of some complex numbers of samples and sliding it to a some samples.

This code was working properly in native compiler in linux 12.04 version. When running the same code in ARM, it doesn't execute that function. It just exits from the code running.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float aa[12]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    float *x=aa,*y=x+6,real=0,imag=0;

    fn_ComplexMultiply_addthem(x,y,6,&real,&imag);

    printf("real value = %f\n",real);
    printf("real value = %f\n",imag);
}

void fn_ComplexMultiply_addthem(float *x, float *y, float len, float *re, float *im)
{
    int j;

    for( j=0; j<len; j+=2)
    {
        *re += (x[j]*(y[j]));
        *re -= (x[j+1]*(-y[j+1]));
        *im += (x[j]*(-y[j+1]));
        *im += (x[j+1]*(y[j]));
    }
}
```

I couldn't understand the reason for it. Each pointer is pointing to some value then it should give me the result whatever the may be right. Instead its just exits from the simulation.

Will it problem with some other things like memory such as stack or others?
Please help me to debug this one.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And also please include the complete Valgrind output. And show us which lines are complained about (with comments in the MCVE).

Comment: When you stepped throuigh with your debugger, which line failed?

Comment: By the way, if you change the initialization of `y` to `y = aa + 6`, what happens then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `y = aa + 6` should be equivalent AFAIK; are you thinking of a compiler bug?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm trying to find something about the order of initialization. My worries is if `y` is initialized before `x`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, maybe. Not sure what the standards says about order of initialisation.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm looking there, but can't seem to find anything. I'll keep looking after lunch.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  if we assign y to y= aa+6. That also encounters the same problem.  When executing the first line  real += (x[j]*(y[j])); the problem occurring and exit from the program simulation.

Comment: That's not your actual code, you're adding and subtracting `float` values to and from pointers. Also, please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can catch crashes, and you can also step through your code line by line. And if possible using tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) could be very helpful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When entering into the  fn_ComplexMultiply_addthem function, there is some valid values are there in both x and y. But when running the first statement it just exit from the simulation. This is what I have observed.

Comment: Posted code cannot possibly "work properly" on any platform. I cannot find a compiler that will compile it, it's full of errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  When running this code in arm platform I am getting error as address trap at some address. could you tell me the causes for address trap.

Comment: Can you please include the actual errors you get? Complete, in full, without modifications, copy-pasted. And of course provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually builds (unless that's your problem)?

Comment: If you can't debug, then can you at least print out the pointers? Like e.g. `printf("x = %p, y = %p, y - x = %d\n", (void *) x, (void *) y, (int) (y - x));`? Do the output look valid? Is the difference between the pointers 24 bytes (6 * 4 (the size of a `float`))?

Comment: That's not valid C. Use a compliant compiler. **Never** just ignore compiler warnings. As a beginner, treat them as errors.

Answer (score 5):

The program is invalid because `fn_ComplexMultiply_addthem` is used before it is declared, and an implicit declaration would not match the actual definition.

In addition, `float len` makes no sense. We don't use floating point numbers for counting.

Change `len` to `int` and add the function declaration before `main`:

```
void fn_ComplexMultiply_addthem(float *x, float *y, int len, float *re, float *im);
```

**ALWAYS** enable compiler warning and treat them as errors (`-Wall -Werror` for gcc and clang).